# has_and_belongs_to_many why would I want to have attr_accessible of the other model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

If I have two models: Experience and Category which are a many to many association, that looks like this:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :experiences
end
```

Why sometimes people add a:

`attr_accessible :category_ids` in the Experience model? I have found myself having to do that so in Rails admin gem I can add categories to a particular experience, but I fail to see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you setup a HABTM relation between Experience and Category, you have, besides other things, available method `Experience#category_ids`. This method returns individual ids of categories the current experience has.

```
Experience.first.category_ids
```

Now this method has also `Experience#category_ids=` variant, so you can use it to assign ids of categories:

```
Experience.first.category_ids = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now when you have a form that let's you select categories for an experience, you have only the ids of the selected categories. When you submit the form, those ids get passed to `Experience#category_ids=` via mass assigment and if you don't have this `category_ids` in `attr_accessible`, you get an error.